# How to hide the Zoom floating panel while screen sharing on Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, zoom-meeting

I want to hide Zoom's floating panel while screen sharing on Ubuntu.

I found [this](https://teacherscollege.screenstepslive.com/a/1241864-hide-zoom-s-floating-meeting-controls) tutorial, but these options are not available on the Linux client (perhaps it only works in Windows/Mac).

Is there any way to force the zoom panel to hide/minimize with some command in Ubuntu?

I installed Zoom as a deb package.